# Share a site with a Microsoft security group using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, pnp-powershell

On a SharePoint Online site, you can access this menu through Site Permissions -> Advanced Permissions Settings -> Grant Permissions.

[image]

I have a Microsoft security group created, and my goal is to give this group Full Control of these sites without making the group a member of the site. I can share the site in this way using the menu above, but **is there a way to do this using PowerShell?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please run the below PowerShell script as admin:**

**Step 1: Get Azure Security Group’s ID**

```
#Install AzureAd package
Install-Module AzureAD

$GroupName = "ADGroup" 
#Connect to Azure AD
Connect-AzureAD -Credential (Get-Credential)

#Get Security Group's SID
Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString $GroupName | Select DisplayName, ObjectId | Format-table
```

[image]

**Step 2: Add Azure Security Group to SharePoint Online Site Collection Administrator’s Group**

```
#Variables
$AdminURL = "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/"
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Echo"
$ADGroupID = "a5c7f51f-1544-45fe-9679-ad99ed6d53ac"
 
$LoginName = "c:0t`.c`|tenant`|$ADGroupID"
 
Try {
    #Connect to SharePoint Online
    Connect-SPOService -url $AdminURL -Credential (Get-Credential)
  
    $Site = Get-SPOSite $SiteURL
  
    Write-host -f Yellow "Adding AD Group as Site Collection Administrator..."
    Set-SPOUser -site $Site -LoginName $LoginName -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $True
    Write-host -f Green "Done!"
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At first I was having difficulty with this, but it was only because I forgot to add myself as a member to the AD group as well as an owner.